# Finding the minimum date value for an ID in different column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

```
df1 = pandas.DataFrame( { 
"ID" : ["11", "11", "11", "11" , "55"] , 
"updated_date" : ["2019/04/03", "2019/05/02", "2019/05/20", "2019/07/01", "2019/03/03"] } )


df2 = pandas.DataFrame( { 
    "ID" : ["11", "11", "11", "11" , "55"] , 
    "other_date" : ["2019/04/09", "2019/05/14", "2019/06/05", "2019/06/05", "2019/03/03"] } )
```

There are two dataframes above. I would like to combine them so that the new dataframe has the ID, the updated_date and the minimum other_date that is larger than the updated date for that ID number.

For ID# = 11 and updated_date = 2019-04-03 there are 4 choices for other date (2019-04-09, 2019-05-14, 2019-06-05, 2019-06-05). The minimum date that is larger than the updated_date is 2019-04-09.

For ID# = 11 and updated_date = 2019-05-02 there are now 3 choices for other date (2019-05-14, 2019-06-05, 2019-06-05). The minimum date that is larger than the updated_date is 2019-05-14 and so on...

**other_dates cannot be reused.**

'NONE' if conditions are not satisfied.

Thank you!

Desired output is this

```
    ID   |  updated_date |  other_date
0   11   |   2019-04-03  |  2019-04-09
1   11   |   2019-05-02  |  2019-05-14
2   11   |   2019-05-20  |  2019-06-05
3   11   |   2019-07-01  |    NONE     (because conditions are not met)
4   55   |   2019-03-03  |  2019-03-03
```

Comment: Hmm, I thought `pd.merge_asof` would be a good solution, however the condition that you can only uniquely match a single time to one of the 'other_date` rows greatly complicates this problem. For one calculating the optimal match is now a lot tricker if matching one row then affects the score of other rows. Might be worth updating your example to illustrate that behavior.